# mask Dollar, brackets and quotes in remote ssh command

Tags: bash, ssh, quoting

I want to do some script on a remote mashine through ssh:

```
ssh Server  "V=\$\(lua -e 'print\(require\(\\\"platform_info\\\"\).get_image_name\(\)\)'\); echo \$V"
```

But this `echo $V` at the end gives me no output.

I tried a lot of different masking with backslashes, but I cannot get this right.

How do I mask the command correctly and get the output of the lua command?

Comment: You can't escape quotes inside a single-quoted string.

Comment: @Barmar: I edited it to a try with double quotes, but still I must have a tiny error here still

Comment: Nesting quotes in the shell is very tricky. Did you look at the duplicate question?

Comment: @Barmar I tried with HEREDOC but that only writes out the code directly instead of executing it on the target

Comment: Often the best way to solve this is to put the code in a script on the remote machine, and then just execute the script with ssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ssh Server 'V=$(lua -e "print(require(\"platform_info\").get_image_name())");echo "$V";'
```

I am not familiar with `lua`, but what I would do is first try to run the `lua` command on the local m/c and observe the quoting. Then place everything in single quotes '...' and then look at other stuff.
`HTH`

Comment: this still seems wrong: `sh: 1: lua: not found`

Comment: Then set your PATH straight first before diving into the quotes.

Comment: Why the PATH. the same problem with the full path: `sh: 1: /usr/bin/lua: not found`. I think your command will start the lua command on my machine and not on the target.

Comment: That means `/usr/bin/lua` does not exist on the remote m/c. You need to first investigate where on the remote m/c is this utility located.

Comment: Sure that exists there. The command works on the server. I don't have lua on my laptop

Comment: Try to see what does the following return: `ssh server '/usr/bin/hostname'` If it returns "server" means ssh is defaulting to your local m/c no matter what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55568/discussion-between-rakesh-sharma-and-rubo77).

Comment: Sure it works. I do a lot of stuff like that. Only the masking is the problem here.